# issue while trying run a device from Android_Emulator

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-emulator, archlinux, wayland

when i run: `/home/Miguer/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Device_Test`
the output is:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.11.0 (build_id 9536276) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /home/Miguer/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-33/google_apis_playstore/x86_64/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-Miguer/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file /home/Miguer/.android/avd/Device_Test.avd/quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
INFO    | Warning: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/home/Miguer/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" ((null):0, (null))
Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
INFO    | Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
[70842:70842:20230610,165240.588572:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[1]    70834 IOT instruction (core dumped)  /home/Miguer/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @Device_Test
```

i'm using Wayland/Hyprland.

i'm tried install qt5-wayland with `sudo pacman -S qt5-wayland`.reinstall android-studio and still have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after someone delete my answere I found the solution to this problem and I dont know If you haven't found the solution yet. It's a QT global variable that was causing my problem, as I mentioned in the previously deleted post. If it is informing the variables, try removing them and restart hyprland to see if it worked. I dont know if yout situation its the same as mine

I comented this two environment variable:

env = QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR,1
env = QT_QPA_PLATFORM,wayland

You can see my configuration in my repo on desenv07/home/.config/hypr-env/env.conf  https://github.com/pedrohms/dotfiles